# Tag Helper Select element is empty even though its data source is not

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2015, tag-helpers

I'm using ASP.NET Core MVC RC2 project using "Database First Model". The database is the famous Northwind database. Everything works fine except that the "Select Tag Helper" (an HTML drop-down list) that is supposed to be populated with the `ViewBag` data is empty even though the `ViewBag` data is **not** empty:

The following action method on the `CustomersController` correctly displays the list of all customers:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    List<Customers> data = repository.SelectAll();
    return View("/views/Northwind/Index.cshtml", data);
}
```

When a user clicks the "Edit" link on a record, the following `Edit` action correctly displays that record values in Edit form *except that the drop-down for countries is empty*:

```
public IActionResult Edit(string id)
{
     Customers data = repository.SelectByID(id);

     var query = (from c in repository.Context.Customers
                    orderby c.Country ascending
                    select new SelectListItem() { Text = c.Country, Value = c.Country }
                 ).Distinct();

   List<SelectListItem> countries = query.ToList();
   ViewBag.Countries = countries;
   return View("/views/Northwind/Edit.cshtml", data);
}
```

The following is the "view" that displays the editable data *except that the drop-down is blank*:

```
@model MVCCoreCR2_Project.Models.Customers

<div class="form-group">
  <label asp-for="Country" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <select asp-for="Country" asp-items="@ViewBag.Countries" class="form-control" />
   <span asp-validation-for="Country" class="text-danger" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note**: During debugging, when I put a break-point at `<select asp-for="Country" asp-items="@ViewBag.Countries" class="form-control" />`  and hover over `@ViewBag.Countries` I can see the countries in the ViewBag are filled in.

Comment: Try using`@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.selectedCountry, IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Countries, new { @class = "form-control" })`

Comment: Please use the correct tag next time. [tag:asp.net-mvc] is for the legacy ASP.NET MVC Webstack (MVC 1 through 5). For ASP.NET Core  use [tag:asp.net-core-mvc]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `<select>` is not a self closing tag. It needs to be

```
<select asp-for="Country" asp-items="ViewBag.Countries" class="form-control"></select>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out the mistake that I would have probably not caught.